my source list is messed up
When I try to run an update I got this,
t:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease [256 kB]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease [126 kB]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

This is my source list file
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
Types: deb
URIs: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg


Seems the problem is not on your side, it's the repositries which are not signed. You can try to switch to a different mirror or wait until the repository maintainer fix the this. The only thing I wonder is why you disabled noble-security, I think it's strongly recommended to have it enabled.

@mook765 can you send me the mirror list or updated source.list file which I can replace

Just add noble-security to the Suites:-line. Here you can find all registered mirrors.
